# Java compareTo method Error :java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

Tags: java, compareto

When I try to make a comparison between two comparable items, the code below  throws this error:

> **java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean**

```
ArrayList<Comparable> list = new ArrayList<Comparable>();

public void myMethod(ArrayList <Comparable> list) {
    for(int i = 1; i < list.size()-1;i++){
        //Comparable current = list.get(i);
        int j = i;
        while((j > -1) && ((list.get(j-1).compareTo(list.get(i))) < 0)){
            j--;
        }
        list.add(j, list.remove(list.get(i)));
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

The purpose of the following line is to compare two the current object in the list to the previous one. *Note that there are ONLY Integer objects in the ArrayList called 'list'.*

```
while(((list.get(j - 1).compareTo(current)) < 0) && (j > -1))
```

Can anyone explain what's going on there?

Comment: what is the data type for list?

Comment: There is too much information missing from your question to allow an accurate answer.  Please provide a proper MCVE

Comment: Integer objects

Comment: Or to put it another way, I can see a few problems with the code *that you have shown us*, but I don't believe that the code that you have shown us is an accurate reflection of what your **real** code is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.util.List` **has two overloaded `remove` methods**: one takes a `int` (index) and returns the removed element, the other one takes an `Object` and returns a `boolean` (`true` if the list contained the specified element, otherwise `false`).

**You code invokes the `remove(Object)` method**, and you're trying to add its `boolean` return value to your list: `list.add(j, list.remove(current));`

Here is the Javadoc for the two overloaded methods:

```
/**
 * Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional
 * operation).  Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one
 * from their indices).  Returns the element that was removed from the
 * list.
 *
 * @param index the index of the element to be removed
 * @return the element previously at the specified position
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the <tt>remove</tt> operation
 *         is not supported by this list
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is out of range
 *         (<tt>index &lt; 0 || index &gt;= size()</tt>)
 */
E remove(int index);
```

and:

```
/**
 * Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
 * if it is present (optional operation).  If this list does not contain
 * the element, it is unchanged.  More formally, removes the element with
 * the lowest index <tt>i</tt> such that
 * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;get(i)==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(get(i)))</tt>
 * (if such an element exists).  Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list
 * contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed
 * as a result of the call).
 *
 * @param o element to be removed from this list, if present
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if this list contained the specified element
 * @throws ClassCastException if the type of the specified element
 *         is incompatible with this list (optional)
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null and this
 *         list does not permit null elements (optional)
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the <tt>remove</tt> operation
 *         is not supported by this list
 */
boolean remove(Object o);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your response, I have a question though: doesn't list.remove(item) remove it from the list and also return it? In what scenario would it return boolean?

Comment: Thank You, I understand now, Ill consult the javadocs more carefully next time

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
list.add(j, list.remove(list.get(i))); // this remove returns a boolean
```

> ```
> >  Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
> >      * if it is present.  If the list does not contain the element, it is
> >      * unchanged.  More formally, removes the element with the lowest index
> >      * <tt>i</tt> such that
> >      * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;get(i)==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(get(i)))</tt>
> >      * (if such an element exists).  Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list
> >      * contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list
> >      * changed as a result of the call).
> >      *
> >      * @param o element to be removed from this list, if present
> >      * @return <tt>true</tt> if this list contained the specified element
> ```

to

```
list.add(j, list.remove(i));  //this remove returns a Comparable
```

> ```
> > Removes the element at the specified position in this list.
> >      * Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their
> >      * indices).
> >      *
> >      * @param index the index of the element to be removed
> >      * @return the element that was removed from the list
> ```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. That was helpful

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your question, it seems like you want to keep only unique integer values in your list. If that is the case, something like this would work.

```
public void getUniqueList(ArrayList<> list){
    for(int i = 1; i < list.size()-1;i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++){
               if (list.get(j) == list.get(j - 1)) {
                   list.remove(j)      //this removes the value if it already appeared the list
               }
            }
        }
    System.out.print(list);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use `Remove` metnod with indexer. Už does mean, you can use your *index i* as parameter comparable `Remove` (it is the secont variant `Remove(your index i)`) function and it should be work. Hope it help.